# Copy a set of files using ADF

Tags: azure, copy, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have 10 files in a folder and want to move 4 of them in a different location.
I tried 2 approaches to achieve this -

1. using lookup to retrieve the filenames from a json file- then feeding it to a for each iterator
2. using metadata to get file names from source folder and then adding if condition inside a for each to copy the files.

But in both the cases, all the files in source folder gets copied.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share a sample, list of file names with type and the selective 4 that you want to move

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There a 3 ways you can consider selecting your files depending on the requirement or blockers.

[image]

Checkout official MS doc: [Copy activity properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties)

**1.** **Dynamic** content for `FilePath` property in Source Dataset.

[image]

**2.** You can use **Wildcard character** in the source folder and file path in the source Dataset.

> Allowed wildcards are: `*` (matches zero or more characters) and `?`
> (matches zero or single character); use `^` to escape if your actual
> folder name has wildcard or this escape char inside.   See more
> examples in [Folder and file filter
> examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#folder-and-file-filter-examples).

[image]

**3. List of Files**

> Point to a text file that includes a list of files you want to copy,
> one file per line, which is the relative path to the path configured
> in the dataset.   When using this option, do not specify file name in
> dataset. See more examples in [File list
> examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#file-list-examples).

[image]

### **Example:**

Parameterize source dataset and set source file name to that which passes the expression evaluation in `IfCondition` Activity.

[image]